# Find out the syntax error in this Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE compare (x INT,  y INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE test INT;

    IF x > y 
        THEN SET test = 1;
    ELSEIF y > x
        THEN SET test = -1;
    ELSE SET test = 0;

    END IF;

    RETURN test;
END
//
```

Can any one show whats the error here? PhpMyAdmin says

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT BEGIN DECLARE test INT; IF x > y THEN SET test = 1; ELSEIF y >' at line 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to `CREATE FUNCTION` instead because procedures cannot return anything, only functions can.

Comment: @Lukman. RE: procedures cannot return anything, only functions can..With MySQL stored procedures that's not entirely true. In MySQL you can declare both IN and OUT parameters in the Stored procedure declaration statement.

Comment: @Jason: The OUT parameters are not the same as RETURN. They are totally different. You can use functions in a SELECT statement precisely because it can `return`. OTOH, even if you are using OUT parameters, you still can't put store proc in a SELECT statement.

Comment: @Lukman. We are talking semantics. Yes I agree, using the RETURN reserved word in a Stored Proc is invalid. However, MySQL stored proc's can "return" values via the OUT parameters. Since Naresh was using MySQL I thought is was worth noting.